# Single page using a database MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create a single page site in ASP.NET MVC (or CORE) for a project to school which will consist of 3 parts 1. A summary of statistics based on data from the database 2. A detailed table containing the entire extract of users from the database 3. Ability to add usera for the database from a manual form and adding a user from the csv file.

I would like to ask if creating 3 components for each of the necessary parts and displaying them in the common view is a good idea? Or Is it better to create one viewmodel that will contain a list of all the data that I will need to use? Or do you have any tips and suggestions for the implementation of this project?

As for the database, it will be the usual SQL database created in the code-first approach. To connect to the database and operations performed on it, I would like to use the interface that will serve as the data access layer.

For all the suggestions, thank you very much. I present the example concept of the page below

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have the 'M' part (the model). Now go out and create your 'V's and 'C's and tie them together with Angular or your technology of choice.

Comment: This will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My standard approach is to 'silo' logic and views by object/type.  In this way, your controllers and views are simplified and specialized (they only need to know how to interact with one type of object).  This approach also lends itself really well to code and view reuse within your web app.

So in your example design, I might be looking at...

Controllers:

- HomeController

  - Method to serve up the main view that will contain your 4 distinct sections
- StatisticController (what type of statistics?  People?)

  - Method to serve up partial view containing statistics
- PersonController

  - Method to serve up partial view containing full list of Person objects
  - Method to serve up partial view containing single-Person upload form
  - Method to serve up partial view containing csv Person file upload
  - Method to accept POST'ed single-Person upload
  - Method to accept POST'ed CSV Person file upload

Views:

- (Home)

  - Main view that contains empty layout for the 4 distinct sections, each of which will ultimately be populated from a partial view with, perhaps, `Html.RenderAction()`)
- (Statistic)

  - StatisticPartial view that contains the stats
- (Person)

  - PersonIndexPartial view that contains the full list of Person objects
  - PersonEditPartial view that contains the single-Person upload form
  - PersonEditBatchPartial view that contains the csv Person file upload form

That's a bit to take in.  I suggest starting with the main form, and getting the general layout set up the way you want it.  Then start plugging partial views into each of the 4 distinct sections, one at a time.  The more you progress, the more things will start to click.